# iOS 8 - Swift - Xcode 6 Beta - working without interface builder (no nibs and no storyboard)

Tags: view, swift, interface-builder, xcode6

I have been searching a lot in the inter webs and Stackoverflow. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much info around the new Xcode version, iOS 8 specifically with Swift and working without the Interface Builder.

The Templates to choose from as a starting point now does not have the option to start with an empty application. The least setup you have is to take the single view application, which already gives you the ViewController and a basic Storyboard.

I hate storyboards and I hate nibs. I want to do everything in code. I tried to delete the storyboard file, instantiate the window, set the rootViewController and make it visible just like in the good old days. the ViewController initializes without nib and bundle.

The result is this a SIGABRT with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/[username]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BC38B690-D30E-44FB-93B1-AB861D03B414/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B6C160C8-67E1-4A74-9F81-55D097262050/blabla.app> (loaded)'
```

I sure hope that I will still be able to do UI without Interface Builder. Anyone has an idea on how to progress? I remember I was able to use an empty application with the previous Beta versions of Xcode 6.

Comment: Deleting your storyboard file is not enough. You also have to delete the reference to "Main" in Deployment Info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion `storyBoards` are awesome. They make the development cycle easy and quick. But if you do not want them you can create a `Single View Application` template.

> Delete the `storyBoard` and Follow these steps
>
> 1) Go to Your Target
>
> 2) Deployment Info
>
> 3) **Main Interface -> Delete Main and keep field empty**

[image]

It will not load a storyboard or any view. Now it's your responsibility to load `Window` and create `rootViewControllers` and `views` programmatically

Comment: What is "Your Target"? I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The method outlined by codester is a good solution, but (in Xcode 6.0.1) the final step - deleting "Main" from the *Main Interface* section - would not work for me; I would delete the string, but as soon as I navigated away from that page or tried to run the app, the field would be repopulated with "Main". I ended up having to manually delete the "UIMainStoryboardFile" key/value entry in the applications Info.plist.

Comment: Thanks. This is the right answer for Xcode 6.1 too.